# Handling Expires Headers in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net

I need advice or suggestions on how to add Expires Headers to my CSS, Image and JavaScript files in ASP.Net MVC.

A key issue is that the software is not in a single location. It is distributed to clients who handle the hosting so I would rather have a solution that doesn't require manual configration in IIS unless it's unavoidable!

I googled around and the majority of answers seem to be focused on content that is returned via a controller. Can't do that for JavaScript files though..

Comment: Why can't you do that for javascript files?

Comment: Because they are not accessed via controller actions?

Comment: There's no reason at all you could not make them accessible via controller actions, just like any other file (images, css, etc). You could even use Routes that make it seem like physical *.js files are being requested... meaning you could do it without changing the javascript file URLs in the site.

Comment: @Andrew - Yeah but that's kind of icky and misleading. This kind of situation is precisely what custom http handlers are intended for.

Comment: @Spencer Ruport - I like the customer handler approach myself - although I'm not sure how a controller action returning the exact same thing your handler does is any more icky or misleading. But mostly, I was wondering why Damien said it *Couldn't* be done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this by writing a custom handler for your javascript files. In your `Web.Config` file of your MVC project look for the `httpHandlers` section. Add something like the following line:

```
<add verb="GET" path="/YourScriptsFolder/*.js" type="Your.Project.Namespace.And.Custom.Handler, Your.Assembly.Name" validate="false" />
```

This will force all requests for js files in that folder through your custom handler which will look something like this:

```
class CustomHandler : IHttpHandler 
{

    #region IHttpHandler Members

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        // Set any headers you like here.
        context.Response.Expires = 0; 
        context.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Parse("3:00:00PM")); 
        context.Response.CacheControl="no-cache"; 

        // Determine the script file being requested.
        string path = context.Request.ServerVariables["PATH_INFO"];
        // Prevent the user from requesting other types of files through this handler.
        if(System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegEx.Match(path, @"/YourScriptsFolder/[^/\\\.]*\.js"))
            context.Response.Write(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path));
    }

    #endregion
}
```

I haven't tested this code so you might run into some issues but this is the basic idea. There are a plethora of examples on ASP.Net custom handlers throughout the web. Here's a good example:

http://www.developer.com/net/asp/article.php/3565541/Use-Custom-HTTP-Handlers-in-Your-ASPNET-Applications.htm

Comment: Cheers! Seems the best approach to take!

Answer (score 5):

Which IIS Version are you using?

If by 'manual IIS configuration' you mean having to open the IIS manager console, IIS 7.5 (and I think 7 as well) allows you to add expires headers to static content using only the web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
  <staticContent>
    <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="00:30:00" />
  </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: This does not work very well (if at all) for images referenced in css files.

Comment: @EdDeGagne Why not?  Are they not being served with the right header?

Comment: @Johnny, Yes, they won't be served with the proper header. I ended up writing a StaticContentController class that handles it properly. I can post the code if you'd like.

Comment: @EdDeGagne Yes I agree it's not ideal. Generally, if your use case allows it, it's advised to turn off <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"> for static content in ASP.NET MVC apps: http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2010/06/dont-use-modules-runallmanagedmodulesfo.html

Answer (score 0):

Another, less complicated option is to add a randomized or versioned query string to the end of the file path.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="somecssfile.css?version=1.0.0.3" />
```

When you change the version, the browser will get a new copy of the file.

Comment: but still the expires header needs to be set.